# How to register or unregister a sensor event listener on click of a button?

Tags: android, android-sensors

I am using the following code to register and unregister SensorEventListener.

```
 //Get the Toggle Button
         final ToggleButton tb=(ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.activate);
         //Listener for ToggleButton
         tb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


             public void onClick(View arg0) {
                 if(tb.isChecked()){
                    //Register the sensor
                     //smanager.
                     smanager.registerListener(this, smanager.getDefaultSensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION,SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
                     Log.v(classname, "Sensor Listener Unregistered");
                 }
                 else{
                      //deRegister the Sensor
                     // Unregister the listener
                     smanager.unregisterListener(this);
                     Log.v(classname, "Sensor Listener Unregistered");

                 }
             }
         });
```

But I am getting the following error.

```
The method registerListener(SensorListener, Sensor, int) is not applicable for the arguments new View.onClickListener(),{},Sensor,int
```

I am not getting this error when writing the same code in `onPause()` method of the activity. What is the problem and how to correct this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`this` refers to the `OnClickListener` instead of your `Activity`.

Change it to this:

```
smanager.registerListener(YourActivityClass.this, smanager.getDefaultSensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
```

Edit to answer your `context` comment:

`registerListener()` requires a `SensorListener`. According to your

> it works in onResume()

comment, I assumed that your `Activity` implements the `SensorListener` interface. The context itself does not implement it therefor you get the same error.

Comment: You were right. But I had tried with context also. Still I got the same error. It should have worked with context right?

Comment: I updated my answer to explain why `context` doesn't work, too.